# Largest number formed by sum and product of digits.

Tags: number-theory

Given a range, say $0-100$, what is the largest number formed by both adding or multiplying the digits? The answer here is $9*9$, actually $9^n$, where n is the number of zeros in the upper range. So, for $100-10000$ the largest is $9*9*9*9$.

Example: Some examples of numbers in the range $10-1000$ are:

562, $5+6*2 = 17$

999, $9*9*9 = 729$

What about more specific ranges, say $5627-6145$?

As an exercise, allow order not to matter. Say, 324 can be $3*4+2$ or $4+3*2$. I will later post some plots i’ve made that visualize the results, but I would like to see some ideas on methods to determine bounds on specific ranges.

Edit: Adding some plots.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: this seems like a programming question. But I'm almost sure it can be solved in linear time over the number of digits.

Comment: In the range $5627$ to $6145$, the winner should be $5\times9\times9\times9$.

Comment: Why is $562$ done as a product making $60$?

Comment: @Yorch For the order-preserving version, we might need quadratic in the number of digits, but this is still exceedingly fast for most ranges one would find in a programming question.